# How disable for prettier-atom the line wrapping in config for arrays and objects?

Tags: atom-editor, prettier

I tried create a .prettierrc in my project root and add there

```
proseWrap: preserve
```

I don't want a wrapping of my javascript array on save file from

```
my_array = [ 1,2,3 ];
```

to

```
my_array = [ 
1,
2,
3 
];
```

But .prettierrc have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

A simple soulution is, use

```
// prettier-ignore
```

This disable for the next code line the prettier formatation

example:

```
// prettier-ignore
my_array = [ 1,2,3 ];
```

see https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

But perhaps anyone know a solution with .prettierrc